# Call to undefined method stdClass:: Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5

I´m having this error when i call my method in blade.

My Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
use Notifiable;

public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}

public function hasAnyRole(){
    if(is_array($roles)){
        foreach ($$roles as $role) {
            if($this->hasRole($role)){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }else{
        if($this->hasRole($roles)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function hasRole($role){
    if($this->roles()->where("name", $role)->first())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}}
```

Then in my home.blade.php

```
@foreach($users as $user)
            {{ $user->hasRole("Admin") }}
            <tr>
                <form action="{{ route("admin.assignrole") }}" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="admin" value="admin"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="cultura" value="cultura"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="opinion" value="opinion"></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Asignar</button></td>
                </form>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

But i´m getting: 
"FatalErrorException in 4ec2afb0bd7b9558404eeeb89a6d9200e0c5639a.php line 18:
Call to undefined method stdClass::hasRole()"

I cant figure why;

Comment: Because your elements in `$users` are obviously not instances of your `User` class, but of `StdClass` only.

Comment: Thanks you very match for your quick answer!
its my first proyect whit laravel and i'm learning
there is an easy way to get my User instance?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank's to CBroe´s help i figured out what´s the problem.
is that im using query builder to get my users to pass it to my view, now i´m using Eloquent Model and all works Ok

Solution:
In my controller class:

```
//$users = DB::table('users')->get();//Query Builder
$users = User::all();//Eloquent
return view('admin.home', compact("users"));
```

thanks for the help